# laravel has wrong default path

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I've uploaded an entire Laravel site. The first time everything was working fine.

Now I had an update and did the same thing all over again. Now the URLs are wrong. Whatever route I choose I get an

> InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
>   View [errors.404] not found.

I also see the following:

> at FileViewFinder->findInPaths('errors.404', array('C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\app\resources\views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 79

Which is really incorrect.

If I echo something in routes.php I can see the echo.

Comment: I think it has to do something with caching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

The OP has website in shared hosting with-out SSH access to run artisan commands.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

**Problem**
Route cached: The OP uploaded local project into shared hosting with cached routes. Which caused routes conflict.

Laravel assumes `c:\xampp\{project_name}` to be local directory while it was different path.

**Solution**
The solution was to remove `bootstrap\cache\` content (Cached routes)

Comment: The files are there. The problem i'm seeing is the the path to the resources are incorrect. See the path C:\xampp\htdocs\app.directevenementen\app\resources\views. This is definetly wrong for a server with my hosting. Is there a way to flush this caching or somewhere in some file adjust the path

Comment: I've deleted all the files in storage/framework/views. Only this didn't fix the problem. Thanks for all the help you've provided so far. Really hope we can come to a solution for this problem. Did you check out the url from the previous comment? Maybe you see something that i'm missing.

Comment: Have you moved the project directory?

Comment: Yes. Since I do not have ssh access yet ftp is the only way to update. So from localhost(virtualhost) to the server